# Upgrade PHP5.1.6 to PHP5.3 in CentOS

Tags: linux, php, centos, installation

In my system, have CentOS 5 and PHP 5.1.6. I tried to update php into version up(5.3)

```
yum update php
result: No Packages marked for Update
```

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You might not want to do this.  If you bodge 5.3.x and assorted dependancies into C5, you will end up with something which isn't a pure C5 system -- and if it breaks, you get to keep all the pieces.  If this is something you think you are going to live with for a while, you might want to use a suitable Fedora to play with while waiting for C6 to come out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following Option to update PHP 5.3.4 successfully !!

For CentOS 5.4

```
rpm --import http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
```

webtatic RPM Install

```
rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/latest.rpm
```

PHP Install

```
yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php
```

PHP Update

```
yum --enablerepo=webtatic update php
```

Comment: Note, Webtatic will be EOLing PHP 5.3 in a few weeks. This answer will no longer be relevant at that point, and stongly suggest PHP 5.5+ is used instead

Answer (score 2):

For CentOS Version 4,

```
wget http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/4/i386/epel-release-4-10.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/el4.i386/remi-release-4-7.el4.remi.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-4*.rpm epel-release-4*.rpm

cd /etc/yum.repos.d

wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/remi-enterprise.repo
rpm --import http://rpms.famillecollet.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi


yum --enablerepo=remi list php
php.i386 5.3.2-1.el4.remi

yum --enablerepo=remi update php
```

I upgraded PHP 5.3.4 in two different systems( CentOS 5.4 & 4.7 ) successfully.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me where some of the others complained about huge lists of missing dependencies such as libc6 etc.

Answer (score 1):

By sheer coincidence I have just written this up for another question. I know this seems to be updating mysql, but it should force php to update and avoid a dependency issue. If php doesn't install by the time you have followed all the steps below, yum remove php and then run: yum --enablerepo=remi install php (and anything else you need)

Follow at your own risk etc:

**NB: for 64-bit CentOS** For 32-bit, leave off the .x86_64 suffixes

```
yum remove mysql mysql-server
su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm'
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-5*.rpm
yum --enablerepo=remi install mysql.x86_64 mysql-server.x86_64
```

You might need to tack on any extras you need to the last yum command - eg: php-mysql php-devel php-pdo

Answer (score 0):

in CentOS 5.6 (and others, presumably), you can:

```
    yum install php53
```

if that gives you trouble, you may first have to

```
    yum erase php5
```